# Unable to install the System.Data.SqlClient

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, nuget-package

I am trying to create Web API that will connect to the SQL server and run the stored procedure. I wanted to install the `System.Data.SqlClient` in to the project so I can give the connection details. But when tried to install that through the `Nuget Manager` it throws error like

```
 Install failed. Rolling back...
 Could not install package 'System.Data.SqlClient 4.3.0'.
 You are trying to install this package into a project that targets. 
 '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5', but the package does not contain any 
 assembly references or content files that are compatible with that 
 framework. For more information, contact the package author.
```

How can I install them or is there any other way of giving the connectionStrings in `web.config`

Comment: Why just dont add dll to the project?

Comment: I don't see them in the Reference Assemblies

Comment: Which nuget version you are using?

Comment: How to check which version we are having

Comment: In Visual Studio, use the Help > About Microsoft Visual Studio command and look at the version displayed next to NuGet Package Manager.

Comment: Try by updating you nuget package. What command you are using to install sql client?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131118/discussion-between-keerti-systematix-infotech-and-user4912134).

Comment: @user4912134, if you want add dll, you have to add reference to the project, then it will be available in it

Comment: Have you ever solved this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could solve this problem with a little workaround for **Xamarin PCL**:

1. Change your PCL target to .NetStandard. You can do it in the PCL project properties.
2. Create a new .NetStandard ClassLibrary project.
3. Add the System.Data.SqlClient and your code
4. Reference the ClassLibrary project dll to the PCL project
5. With this library you can use the SqlClient.

**In your case with asp.net:** Perhaps, you can try to create a .NetFramework ClassLibrary and follow the steps above.

I hope it will help you!